# Put results in a table and then sorted output

Tags: sorting, powershell, object, hash

I am writing a script which produces two outputs with in a foreach loop , one string `$server` and one integer `$util`.(lets say I get 20 results)
What is the simplest approach to put my results in a table while running the loop and then I can output them sorted (descending) after the loop is finished ?

```
SERVER          UTIL
------          ----
SERVER001       95
SERVER002       74
SERVER003       32
SERVER004       12
```

Comment: Can you show us how you build your objects? Unless we see the input we cant accurately make the output. From the comments I don't think you have a single object array but a couple of variables.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort the results in descending order you will have put the results in an array and then sort outside the loop like so:

```
$arr = @()
foreach ($item in $collection)
{
    $arr += [pscustomobject]@{
        Server = $item.server
        util = $item.util


    }
}


$arr | Sort-Object -Property Util -Descending
```

Comment: Can you check if your syntax is correct ? I am getting this
At line:6 char:29
+     $arr += [pscustomobject]@['Server' = $server ,'UTIL' = ([math]::Round((([mat ...
+                             ~
Unrecognized token in source text.

Comment: i have no idea what kind of collection you are using so if you can post some more code showing the collection maybe i can help to modify the code

Comment: @Fenomatik On top of what Kiran is saying...You are also not running the code in the answer. You are making changes. Does the code run without you using Math

Comment: `$collection | ForEach-Object{[pscustomobject]@{Server = $_.server;util = $_.util}}| Sort-Object -Property Util -Descending` would make better sense. No need for the rebuilding of an array